# SBJson displays null

Tags: ios, json, sbjson

I am trying to parse some json data with SBJson to show the current temperature. The example code from this tutorial works perfect: [Tutorial: Fetch and parse JSON](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/)

When I change the code to my json feed i get a null. I am kind of new to JSON but followed every tutorial and documentation I found. The json source i used: [JSON Source](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=seatle&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=c0901b281c095607121605)

My code with sbjson:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
self.responseData = nil;

NSArray* currentw = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"current_weather"];

//choose a random loan
NSDictionary* weathernow = [currentw objectAtIndex:0];

//fetch the data
NSNumber* tempc = [weathernow objectForKey:@"temp_C"];
NSNumber* weatherCode = [weathernow objectForKey:@"weatherCode"];


NSLog(@"%@ %@", tempc, weatherCode);
```

and of course I have already implemented the other sbjson code.

Comment: If this is a new project, you should consider using Apple's official [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Learn how to read JSON -- it takes maybe 5 minutes:  http://www.json.org/

Comment: Contradictory to your question *SBJson doesn't display ANYTHING*. It is just there for parsing JSon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `current_weather` key in the JSON data you posted. The structure is:

```
{ "data": { "current_condition": [ { ..., "temp_C": "7", ... } ], ... } }
```

Here's a visual representation:

[image: JSON visual representation]

Therefore, to get to `temp_C`, you'd need to first obtain the top-level `data` property:

```
NSDictionary* json = (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];
NSDictionary* data = [json objectForKey:@"data"];
```

then, from that, obtain the `current_location` property:

```
NSArray* current_condition = [data objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
```

and finally, from the `current_location` array, get the element you're interested in:

```
NSDictionary* weathernow = [current_condition objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

Also note that `temp_C` and `weatherCode` are strings, not numbers. To transform them to numbers, instead of:

```
NSNumber* tempc = [weathernow objectForKey:@"temp_C"];
NSNumber* weatherCode = [weathernow objectForKey:@"weatherCode"];
```

you could use something like:

```
int tempc = [[weathernow objectForKey:@"temp_C"] intValue];
int weatherCode = [[weathernow objectForKey:@"weatherCode"] intValue];
```

(or `floatValue` / `doubleValue` if the value is not supposed to be an `int`, but rather a `float` or a `double`)

You would then use `%d` (or `%f` for `float` / `double`) as a format string:

```
NSLog(@"%d %d", tempc, weatherCode);
```

Comment: Thanks i got it working!! There was a slight problem in the code you supplied: NSDictioanry* current_condition = [data objectForKey:@"current_condition"]; 
Needs to be:
    NSArray *currentConditions = [data objectForKey:@"current_condition"];

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` instead of `JSONValue`.

```
NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
 NSLog(@"jsonDict:%@",jsonDict);
```

In your link, there is no `current_weather` key.

```
NSString* tempc = [[[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"temp_C"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided link returns json without current_weather parameter. There is only current_condition parameter, please review this.